# How to solve this propblem

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Code of the case editing form. Validation of this form needs to be implemented We are using useForm from react-hook-form and the yup lib. How to solve this propblem, we tried to change the schema case and form type.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'validate')
```

```
Schema.ts

export const SchemaCase = (categories: CaseListCategory) => {
  yup.object().shape({
    categoryId: yup
      .object()
      .required('Пожалуйста, выберите тематику')
      .oneOf(categories.listCaseCategory.map(category => category.label)),
    description: yup.string().required('Пожалуйста, опишите ситуацию и желаемый результат')
  })
```

```
EditCase.ts 


  const handleOnChange =
    (triggerName: keyof CaseParamsCreate, onChangeCallback: (event: string | React.ChangeEvent<Element>) => void) =>
    (value: TriggerValue) => {
      trigger(triggerName)
      return onChangeCallback(value)
    }

  return WithLoading(
    () => (
      <div className="pb-35">
        <div className=" container mt-20">
          <Text text="Редактировать дело" variant="Title1" />
          <Text className="text-myCol-darkGray mt-8 max-w-[615px]" text={name} variant="Text3" />
        </div>
        <form className="mt-30 container" onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => onUpdateSubmit(params.id, data))}>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="categoryId"
            render={({ field: { onChange } }) => {
              return (
                <ThemeSelect
                  {...register('categoryId')}
                  className="mt-30"
                  width={'w-88'}
                  onChange={handleOnChange('categoryId', onChange)}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
```

Tried to change the schema case and form type

```
export const SchemaCase = (categories: CaseListCategory) => {
  yup.object().shape({
    categoryId: yup
      .object()
      .required('Пожалуйста, выберите тематику')
      .oneOf(categories.listCaseCategory.map(category => category.label)),
    description: yup.string().required('Пожалуйста, опишите ситуацию и желаемый результат')
  })
}
```

```
export type CaseParamsCreate = {
  categoryId: string
  description: string
  documents: { content: string; name: string }[]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidelines for [ask] and then [edit] the question so that its title illustrates the issue you're having.  Currently it's too vague to be useful.  Good luck!